# Implement KeyCloak Role Storage and Role Mapping over external Database

Tags: keycloak, user-roles, external-data-source, keycloak-spi

I have a requirement of implementing KeyCloak over external Database and should be able to CRUD users and roles and along with mapping/assigning them.

I also able to develop CRUD Users using User Storage SPI, but was unable to find any content regarding Role Storage SPI or any implementations on github.

So it would be really helpful if there any links or github implementations would be provided for the CRUD of roles over external DB and also linking created roles with created users.

Comment: Did you find any solution to implement role storage? I've the same kind of problem.

Comment: @zaerymoghaddam No I couldn't find any solution till now?!

Comment: Me neither. I just noticed that there is a RoleStorageProvider in the master branch of the Keycloak source. So probably on Keycloak 12 we would have such an option.